# Is there any way I can pass variables to scriptella e.g. environment or -D parameter?

Tags: scriptella

I need to invoke same `xmls` with slight variation in certain parameters. I thought of writing `etl.properties`, but then I realize I have to write the properties file name in the `xml` and that is not what I want.

Ideally I was looking for to pass parameters to `Scriptella` using command line. Apparently I could not find it in any document.

Any ideas?

Comment: Good point, I think it was already requested once. I've added a [ticket](http://javaforge.com/issue/186151) to add support for passing properties in the shell script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can directly use a Java launcher to pass system properties:

```
java -jar -Dproperty=value scriptella.jar [etl_file_name]
```

Or an alternative launching option if multiple jars needed on the classpath. (This is rarely necessary because jars can be added in the connection declaration):

```
java -Dproperty=value -cp scriptella.jar:additiona_jars.jar scriptella.tools.launcher.EtlLauncher [etl_file_name]
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I wanted.